# Add UIImage directly into FBSDKShareLinkContent with Swift?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uiimage

I have the FBSDK sharing function working with the following code:

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to

        let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = NSURL(string: self.url_string)
        content.contentTitle = self.title_text
        content.contentDescription = self.desc_text
        content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://image.png")

        let button : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
        button.shareContent = content
        button.frame = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100) * 0.5, 50, 100, 30)
        button.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }
```

The problem is that I don't have an imageURL, I have an image taken directly from the app's camera function stored as a UIImage variable. How can I attach an image to this FBSDKShareLinkContent without the image being hosted online? I'm using FBSDKShareLinkContent because I'm also sharing a link w/ title & description.

Edit, I'm trying FBSDKSharePhoto (as someone suggested) with this code, which lets me post the photo, but I can't get the URL to link properly even though `content.contentURL` is defined as it was before.

```
let photo : FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
        photo.image = self.scaledImage
        photo.userGenerated = true

        let content : FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
        content.contentURL = NSURL(string: self.url_string)
        content.photos = [photo]

        let button : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
        button.shareContent = content
        button.frame = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100) * 0.5, 50, 100, 30)
        button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.descLabel.center.y + 51 + 30) // 51 = 1/2 of height of descLabel, 30 = space below
        self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: For local photo share you can use `FBSDKSharePhotoContent`. Link share actually shares a link(online content) and imageUrl property attached to it is reference image to it. I also wanted to do what you are asking for but couldn't find anything...

Comment: The thing is I want to share a link alongside the image with a title & description. I didn't think I could do that with FBSDKSharePhotoContent

Comment: If I use FBSDKSharePhotoContent I can get the image to post, but how do I get the link in there?

Comment: FYI, I added my current code up to the top post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that the `FBSDKSharePhotoContent` is the way to go, but there is currently a bug that Facebook is aware of, which is causing the image & link to not work together.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949486035103197/

They say this should be updated in the next Facebook app update v31. v30 was updated May 7 and FB releases updates every two weeks, so I'll check back in a week and confirm that the functionality is fixed.

Comment: is it fixed? Even I have the same requirement?